# What happens to handmaids who accomplish their purpose?

Tags: the-handmaids-tale

In *The Handmaid's Tale*, handmaids are fertile woman who are forced to live with commanders who have infertile wives. The handmaids' purpose is to receive their commander's seed and provide new children to the population.

In the show on Hulu, we see Genine is able to become pregnant and birth a healthy girl to her commander. She is kept around after the birth as a wet-nurse to the new baby, but eventually (as seen in Episode 9), is forced to leave her commander's house and serve a new commander. Presumably this cycle will continue until the handmaid becomes infertile due to age.

It is discussed that if a handmaid fails to provide a child to their commander (after a number of tries) they are shipped off to work in the colonies.

However, is it ever discussed what happens to a handmaid that was able to birth multiple healthy children, and has simply reached the age of infertility? Are they sent to the colonies with the unsuccessful handmaids, do they become marthas (house servants), new aunts, or are they rewarded in some way and able to live as wives?

Answer (score 14):

If you're willing to accept the book's logic, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Handmaid%27s_Tale#Women) states:

> .... Handmaids who successfully bear children to term assist in raising them for a short time, and are then sent away to a new assignment, never to see the child they bore again. Their success as a Handmaid, however, means they will **never be declared an "Unwoman"** and sent to the Colonies, **even if they never have another baby**.

Comment: I am willing, and actually expecting the answer to come from the book... This does answer part of the question in saying what 'does not happen' to the handmaids, but this does not answer the question as to 'what does' happen to them... Still +1 for narrowing it down.

Comment: You might want to swap the wiki quote out with the book quote: "*She’ll be allowed to nurse the baby, for a few months, they believe in mother’s milk. After that she’ll be transferred, to see if she can do it again, with someone else who needs a turn. But she’ll never be sent to the Colonies, she’ll never be declared Unwoman. That is her reward."*